# Extract specific xml child items from xml stored as byte datatype from a variable into a list in python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, nested-loops, xml.etree

I am writing a python script which is expected to get output values in bytes format into a variable. There are two nest for loops. The first for loop collects the name of a tenant and puts it into a function to get the list of namespaces inside it. This list of namespace is an XML file and is output as bytes datatype.

An example is shown below:

```
Source = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><namespaces><name>Namespacename1</name><name>Namespacename2</name>'

import lxml
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

for tenant in tenants:
    c.GET('/mapi/tenants/'+tenant+'/namespaces')#This comes from another sdk so ignore this
    c.response_status # this also is part of the sdk so ignore this
    source = c.read() # This operation is also part of the sdk so ignore this as well
    print(source)
    nslist = et.fromstring(source)
```

The point is, I need to get many child items called 'name' from each of these xml outputs(that are in format "bytes") that is stored inside the variable called source and each of those 'name' values have to be appended into a new list variable.

Some of the xml responses are empty and I keep getting the xml parse error when I try to loop through each of them to perform this action. I tried the if else condition to try and ignore that. That failed too!

I did a lot of reading on the xml.etree documentation and also tested several for-loops. Nothing helped unfortunately. 
Can some one help sort this for me?

Comment: The small et in et.fromstring funtion is actually imported from -- from lxml import etree as et

Comment: Without knowing how the actual data looks like in practice, it is impossible to answer to the question

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. I shall simplify it.                                   Lets say I have a variable called "source" which is an xml output in datatype bytes. I can do the below operation to fetch each child item called "name" from it. This is easy if the variable value was a static entry. But in my case, this comes inside a for loop and the xml input into source keeps changing on every loop. I am unable to fetch the individual "name" values for each such xml sources during every iteration of the main for loop. Sample code in next comment

Comment: >>> import lxml
>>> source = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><namespaces><name>Building</name><name>Active</name><name>system</name></namespaces>'
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> Info = etree.fromstring(source)
>>> infoperitem = Info.findall('name')
>>> infoperitem[0].text
'Building'
>>> infoperitem[1].text
'Active'
>>> infoperitem[2].text
'system'

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I have given a sample. The code doesn't organise well in the comments section. So I request you to consider the ">>>" to be a newline. At the end when I try to print out the name value from the xml. I type ">>> infoperitem[0].text", I get the answer" 'Building' ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question myself. I just used the enumerate option to resolve this.

As mentioned in my example. I have a variable in bytes format containing an xml file. I needed the child items called name from the xml files. I used the open source module called lxml. You can also use the xml module(ElementTree) inbuilt in python3.

Below is the solution. I have the variable called source.

```
source = b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>.<namespaces><name>Building</name><name>Active</name><name>system</name></namespaces>'

nsinfo = nslist.findall('name')
    for q, value in enumerate(nsinfo):
        nsname = str(value.text)
        print(nsname)

Building
Active
System
```

This will give you the specific value from the xml file that you are looking for. Problem solved!.

You can look at the below link to understand better.

https://github.com/Solitarystate/Hitachi-Content-Platform-Capacity-Reporting/blob/master/hcpcapacityreporting_xml.py